# load div then delay load next in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

Hi I have a gallery which has left floated divs in, the pictures are the backgrounds for each div, what i want is for each picture to load with a slight delay so first will load then wait say 5 seconds then the 2nd etc in a sequence, i have seen it on sites but keep forgetting to bookmark it, if possible in jquery.

i did try query but i can only get the whole lot to fadein when i want each div to fade in

so with this code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

the child elements will fade in one at a time. the first then a delay of 5 seconds and then the next and so on.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$('#parent .child')
    .hide()
    .each(function(index){
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout( function(){ $(_this).fadeIn(); }, 5000*index );
    });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eGWx9/1/

Comment: This is a very good example of the effect in Jquery, although it doesn't seem to hide the last image before showing the next? Unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @Decad, the OP did not ask for any hiding .. just showing with a delay between each one..

Comment: Really elegant answer, great call on the 5000*index.

Answer (score 2):

I like @Gaby aka G. Petrioli answer the best, but Ill post mine anyway.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PkZbq/)**

**CSS**

```
.child{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
showElements($('#parent'));

function showElements(element){
    element.children('div').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':hidden')){
            $(this).fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function(){showElements(element)}, 1000);  
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First set all your children to hidden `.child {display:none;}`

Then fade them in recursively:

```
function fade_in(e){
    $(e).fadeIn('slow',function(){
        if($(e).next().length > 0){
            setTimeout(function(){fade_in($(e).next());},5000);
        }
    });
}
fade_in($('.child:first-child'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B7Qgk/1/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

For example:

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      $("div.second").slideUp(300).fadeIn(400);
    });
</script>
```